# member variable string gets treated as Tuple in Python

Tags: python, class

I am currently learning Python with the help of CodeAcademy. My problem may be related to their web application, but my suspicion is I am just wrong on a very fundamental level here.

If you want to follow along I am referring to CodeAcademy.com -> Python -> Classes 6/11

My code looks like this:

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model,
        self.color = color,
        self.mpg = mpg

my_car = Car("DeLorean", "silver", 88)
print my_car.model
print my_car.color
print my_car.mpg
print my_car.condition
```

What is suppossed to happen, is, that every member variable of the object `my_car` gets printed on screen. I was expecting that like `condition`, `color` and `model` would be treated as a string, but instead get treated as a `Tuple`.

The output looks like this:

```
('DeLorean',) #Tuple
('silver',) #Tuple
88 
new #String
None
```

Which leads to the validation failing, because CA expects "silver" but the code returns `('silver',)`.

Where is the error in my code on this?

Comment: I'm grateful for your question.  I teach Python, and the trailing comma issue.  This is the first time I have come across a real live example of someone making this mistake!  Thanks.

Comment: Aye, it is very hard, to unlearn everything one does know about other languages. Every so often I write `object = new class` just because I am used to it. I guess I will be stumbling about syntactical mashups very often the upcoming weeks.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

In your `__init__`, you have:

```
    self.model = model,
    self.color = color,
```

which is how you define a tuple. Change the lines to

```
    self.model = model
    self.color = color
```

without the comma:

```
>>> a = 2,
>>> a
(2,)
```

vs

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a
2
```

Comment: That was it - simply lost in translation somewhere between C# and Python. Cheers. Accept will follow as soon as the lock has bee lifted.

Comment: So, simple. And yet I was lost due to this

Comment: This is the second time I've come across this, why am I so stupid

Comment: awful syntactic sugar -_-

Comment: This helped me in 2022 (the future is awful, don't come here).

Comment: It's a subtle one, especially if you're used to dealing with structs in C++. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 27):

You've got a comma after those attributes in your constructor function.

Remove them and you'll get it without a tuple

Comment: These are no properties, but mere attributes.

Answer (score 7):

yes, you have to remove comma from instance variables. `from self.model = model, to self.model = model`

Nice to see, you are using **Class variable** concept, 
"`condition`" is class variable and "`self.model`", "`self.color`", "`self.mpg`" are instance variables.