# Issue serializing JSON data

Tags: python, json, serialization, format

I'm trying to serialize my Python Objects to JSON. I have managed to get it to successfully serialize correctly, however it seems to be serializing everything, including single values, as arrays. I'd like the output to be as condensed as possible, with single values being printed alongside their key-value on the same line. I seem to be having problems parsing the saved JSON with the values saved like this.

This is a snippet of the output I'm getting:

```json
{
    "sensorid": [
        "b8:27:eb:f3:b0:e0"
    ],
    "temperature": [
        17
    ],
...
```

Whereas, ideally, I'd like this snippet to look like:

```json
{
    "sensorid": "b8:27:eb:f3:b0:e0",
    "temperature": 17,
...
```

And here is the code I am using to generate it:

```py
class Alert(object):
    def __init__(self, alerttype, timestamp, reading, message):
        self.alerttype = alerttype,
        self.timestamp = timestamp,
        self.reading = reading,
        self.message = message


class Packet(object):
    def __init__(self, sensorid, temperature, humidity, fan_on, fan_speed, vent_open, alerts: List[Alert]):
        self.sensorid = sensorid,
        self.temperature = temperature,
        self.humidity = humidity,
        self.fan_on = fan_on,
        self.fan_speed = fan_speed,
        self.vent_open = vent_open,
        self.alerts = alerts


testA = Alert(0, int(math.floor(time.time())), "", "DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM")
testB = Alert(1, int(math.floor(time.time())), "", "DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM")
testC = Alert(2, int(math.floor(time.time())), "", "DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM")
testP = Packet("b8:27:eb:f3:b0:e0", int(17), int(23), "True", 100, True, [])

testP.alerts.append(testA)
testP.alerts.append(testB)
testP.alerts.append(testC)

jsonStr = json.dumps(testP.__dict__, default=lambda x: x.__dict__, indent=4)
print(jsonStr)
```

Is there something I have missed that has caused it to output this way?

I'd appreciate any ideas anyone may have, TIA.

Comment: I'd say that passing `testP.__dict__` is not the best solution. Wouldn't it be better to write `serialize` method, that returns everything as expected? But possibly wait for more opinions :)

Comment: @DawidGacek I did consider that, although I was hoping that there might be a neater library function method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved, finally!

It was due to the fact that in my class definition I had accidentally left trailing commas after the attribute definitions, casuing them to be treated as `Tuples` rather than singular items.

The class should look like this:

```py
class Alert(object):
    def __init__(self, alerttype, timestamp, reading, message):
        self.alerttype = alerttype  # <- Trailing commas removed
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.reading = reading
        self.message = message
```

Solved using the help of these threads:

[Python explicitly define object attribute type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061148/python-explicitly-define-object-attribute-type)

[member variable string gets treated as Tuple in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654671/member-variable-string-gets-treated-as-tuple-in-python)