# Python explicitly define object attribute type

Tags: python, class, oop, types

I have created a class of attributes, and have tried to populate this class with my values, and then retrieve them later in the code, however I am getting an issue where the values are all seen as `Tuples` rather than their actual data types.

For example, I have the class `Alert`:

```py
class Alert(object):
    def __init__(self, alerttype: int, timestamp: int, reading: str, message: str):
        self.alerttype = alerttype,
        self.timestamp = timestamp,
        self.reading = reading,
        self.message = message
```

If I want to get the `alerttype` attribute of a given object instance (`myObject`), I would do:
`val = myObject.alerttype`, however, this seems to return a Tuple, rather than an integer

```py
Output: (0,)
Expected: 0
```

I thought of perhaps overriding the `__getattr__` attribute for each attribute, and stripping the brackets and comma, however this seems like quite a hacky solution, surely there must be a way to do this neatly that I'm missing?

Would appreciate anyone's ideas, thanks.

Comment: Remove all the trailing commas in your init! `a,` is a singleton tuple `(a,)`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Oh! Can't believe I missed that! I've been writing too much JSON :/ Thanks :)

Comment: Quite a common gotcha in Python =) Happens a lot when copy'n'pasting